# Going to a navigation controller inside a Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, viewcontroller

This is how my storyboard is laid out:

[image]

The first View controller on the left is the initial VC and this decides which VC to go to if you are signed in or not. I have not decided to implement a Tab Bar controller to have a tab bar. However I need a navigation controller going to each VC coming out of the tab bar.

If I use this code to navigate over, it shows a black screen (It worked fine before adding a Tab Bar Controller):

```
let mainNavController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.mainNavController)
view.window?.rootViewController = mainNavController
view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

If I use this code, all of the segues show modally:

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
view.window?.rootViewController = viewController
view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And as s last resort I tried to go straight to the Tab Bar controller but then I got this error:

> Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x600000e88840>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'tabBarController'

So my problem is I want to navigate from a View controller programatically to the show the Tabbed VCs and use a navigation controller so all of the segued view controllers don't show modally.

(I have tried using individual Navigation Controllers for each of the tabbed vCs but that shows a black screen also)

This was the original with the tabbed VCs having individual Navigation Controllers:

[image]

And the error I got when trying to programatically go to that was

> Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x600000e88840>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'tabBarController'

Even though it does

Comment: In your storyboard I see a segue from `NavigationController` to `UITabBarController` if you are trying to put `UITabBarController` to NavigationController stack you cant, you cant embed a NavigationController to `UITabBarController`

Comment: As I said in the question I said it was a last resort, in the brackets at the end it explains how I used to have it